# Is there some way to change color of a label when the input which is a child element in sibling div is brought in focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<form>
<label>Hello there</label>
    <div>
      <input/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there some way we can style the label when the input inside the div is brought into focus. Please give suggestion for React or HTML without the use of jQuery.
For instance when the input is brought in focus, the color of the label changes.

Comment: Your label is not linked to your input (so if you have several input and label elements, your code won't know which is which). Use the `for` attribute on the label (`htmlFor` in React) or put the input *inside* the label.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `label:focus-within { color: red; }`.

This will style the label whenever any of its children has focus.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: This is the best answer. There is no need to do with JS what you can do with CSS. JS is much more performance-expensive compared to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [Color, setColor] = React.useState('#e31f1f');
  const newColor = '#1fe3b2';
  const OldColor = '#e31f1f';
  const changeCollorFunction = (color: string) => {
    setColor(color);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label
          id="change-color"
          style={{
            color: Color,
          }}
        >
          Hello there
        </label>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onFocus={() => {
              changeCollorFunction(newColor);
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              changeCollorFunction(OldColor);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [focuse,setFocuse]=useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label style={{backgroundColor:focuse?'red':'transparent'}}>Hello there</label>
    <div>
      <input onFocus={()=>setFocuse(true)}/>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```